# I have many SQL Server databases like Company_1, Company_2......... with same schema (drop table from all databases)

Tags: sql-server

I don't want to use this query

```
use Company_1
DROP TABLE user
```

and

```
use Company_2
DROP TABLE user
```

I just want to execute single query and user table should delete from all databases.

Comment: create a dynamic query and execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dynamic sql with selecting from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` manage table:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''
SELECT @sql += ' Drop table [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].['+ TABLE_NAME + ']'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'user'
Exec Sp_executesql @sql
```